# Exact test for checking conservative forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, differential-geometry, vector-fields, conservative-field

> What is the nature of this force on the path $x^2+y^2=1$?
> $$\tag1\vec F=\frac{-y\,\hat{i }+x\,\hat{j}}{x^2+y^2}.$$

I tried two methods, but they give different answers:

1. For this specific path it simplifies to
   $$\tag2\vec F=-y\,\hat{i}+x\,\hat{j}$$
   which is a non-conservative force cf. the curl test.
2. But using the general method i.e. curl test on eq. (1) shows it is conservative.
   So what is the mystery?

Comment: Your question is actually rather little to do with the physics and much more to do with the abuses of mathematics that is common in physics. You should learn more differential forms, and realise that this is precisely the difference between [closed and exact differential forms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) In short, you have a puncture at the origin, and the curl is infinite there, in just the way to give you a winding number.

Comment: This [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989) might be helpful. Your vector field does in fact have a lot to do with certain branches of physics. In the first few chapters of Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics* it is explained what it has to do with the Wu-Yang monopole that was in 1975 the first solution to the Yang-Mills field equations. That's enough buzz words now to find more material easily, even here on PSE.

Comment: That helped but still I'm not crystal clear regarding this mystery. Please post a detailed explanation as an answer

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent So should I move it to MSE?

Comment: It might be more appropriate there, but they will most likely close it as a duplicate. I'm sure there are plenty of questions about these, because this is such a standard thing to look at. Maybe you will immediately understand it better if I tell you that the curl is not zero, but rather that the curl is a Dirac delta distribution? That is, it kinda behaves as conservative as long as you do not go around the origin or cross the origin. If you do, then it is actually not conservative. If this does not help, you should pick up good lecture notes on differential forms and learn them patiently.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent has given the explanation in a pretty good nutshell. It matters what your closed loops are doing. Look at the picture I produced in that linked answer. If still not crystal clear we need to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with the closed and differential forms so that might be the reason I'm not able to understand it. Till now I thought that curl test is a guarantee for checking the force as conservative or non conservative but know I got that it is not correct everywhere. As a conclusion I just want to know that is this force conservative or not?

Comment: I hope you looked at the picture over there. Even for someone who has no clue about maths it should be intuitively clear that if he or she travels clockwise around a closed loop that circles the origin he or she lost potential energy. That loop is therefore not conservative. If the traveler does ***not*** circle around the origin he or she returns to the starting level. Same potential energy. Conservative. As a physicist you should expect a bit more than just a simplistic (and wrong) rule that says: curl free is always conservative.

Comment: Yes I saw the picture but how does it explain if one is not encircling around origin?

Comment: Simple. Then every closed loop starts and ends at the same level of the potential $\phi\,.$ These are the loops that don't even notice that there is a singularity. They can be contracted to a single point. Revisit what you learned about the independence of the line integral of force times $ds$ (work done) of the path you choose between two points.

Comment: You don’t **need** differential forms for this (you only require it if you want to study higher-dimensional analogues of the phenomenon you just observed); note this is not meant to dissuade you trom learning them (you definitely should, they’re great). At your level though, what you need is to understand what the theorem says vs what it does not because that’s the source of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mystery; if anything it’s a misunderstanding of what the theorem says vs what it does not say, in particular confusing a theorem and a partial converse.

The curl test says

> **Theorem 1.**
>
> Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be an open set and let $F:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}^3$ be a (continuously differentiable) vector field. If $F$ is
> conservative then the curl of $F$ vanishes identically.

This is a one-way implication and be careful with the meaning of an if-then statement. It is often phrased in the contrapositive format “if the curl is non-zero then the vector field is not conservative”.

The above theorem has a **partial** converse:

> **Theorem 2.**
>
> Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be an open set and let $F:\Omega\to \Bbb{R}^3$ be a (continuously differentiable) vector field. If $\Omega$ is *simply-connected* and the curl of $F$ vanishes identically, then $F$ is conservative.

In your case you would like to apply theorem 2. However you cannot, because the domain you’re working on is not simply connected (ok and even if you didn’t know that the punctured plane or $\Bbb{R}^3$ with  $z$-axis removed is not simply connected, at the very least you don’t yet know if it is or not so you can’t apply the theorem since you don’t even know if the assumptions are satisfied). So there is no contradiction anywhere. Bottom line is don’t invoke a theorem without first checking the precise statement, and second, without verifying if the hypothesis are satisfied.

Your vector field is not conservative because you found a loop for which the line integral is non-zero (and recall that one of the equivalent definitions of conservative is that the line integral over every loop is zero).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.